# Help with Evaluation controll/hold all attributes?

Tags: evaluation, core-language, hold

I'm making a sort of symbolic derivator, which needs to take its formulas in unevaluated form.

```
SetAttributes[derDer, HoldAll]
...
derDer[Plus[a_, b_], aux_] := Plus[ derDer[a, aux] , derDer[b, aux] ]
derDer[Times[a_, b_], aux_] := Plus[ Times[a, derDer[b, aux]], Times[derDer[a, aux] , b] ]
derDer[a_, aux_] := Condition[derDer[Evaluate[a], aux], Hold[a] != Hold[Evaluate[a]]]
```

The last line doesn't work well. I want the expression to see if its first (held) argument is equal to its own evaluation, and if it isn't so, run itself again with the evaluated argument. I don't understand how  `Hold` , `Eval` and `HoldAll` work well enough to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by replacing the last expression with

`derDer[a_, aux_] := Condition[derDer[Evaluate[a], aux], Not[Hold[a] === Hold[Evaluate[a]]]]`

The problem was `==` returning unevaluated cases.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286736/difference-between-and-in-mathematica).

Comment: You could just use `=!=` instead.